# Have any [other] countries fired 50% [or more] of government workers (say over the course of one year)?

Tags: government, comparative-politics, employment, argentina, neoliberalism

[According](https://reason.com/2024/03/04/milei-closes-state-news-agency-telam-for-spreading-propaganda/) to *Reason* magazine:

> Since taking office in December, Milei has cut the number of government ministries from 18 to eight and fired over 50 percent of all government workers.

I'm curious: how does this compare with other ['shock therapy'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_therapy_(economics)) programmes, e.g. during privatization in Eastern Europe after the fall of Soviet-aligned regimes or some other events of government downsizing elsewhere? Are there numerically comparable reductions in government workforce in some of those?

(FWTW, perusing the Wikipedia article finds that the 1985 Bolivian reforms involved "Laying off two-thirds of the employees of the state oil and tin companies and freezing the pay of the remaining employees and public sector workers". But I'm not sure how much those represented of total gov't workers.)

Comment: I find no references in Spanish press to Milei firing 50% of government workers. The only numbers I find are 5000 to 7000 thousands temporary workers who were not renewed on December. Given that Reason seems to have a liberal outlook ("Free markets") and that Milei has become sort of the current Saint Patron of liberals (kind of like a Trump without the embarassing moments), I would first verify the veracity of the claim.

Comment: @SJuan76: feel free to post a frame-challenge answer. https://www.france24.com/en/live-news/20240222-argentine-government-shuts-anti-discrimination-agency says he fired 30,000 state employees. Dunno if that's 50% though.

Comment: I can tell you that 30.000 is far from being half of the public workers. VERY far from it.

Comment: @SJuan76 According to the [ILO](https://www.ilo.org/shinyapps/bulkexplorer48/?id=EES_PUBL_SEX_JOB_NB_A&ref_area=ARG&sex=SEX_T&classif1=JOB_CONTRACT_TOTAL&latestyear=TRUE), Argentina had about 2.3 million public sector employees in 2022.

Comment: @xyldke: given how _Reason_ puts that after the number of slashed ministries, they might mean just 'workers' in the central government, or just among ministries.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat Any question about (labour) statistics hinges on definitions. Do you include employees of state-owned enterprises? Do you include things like military/police/healthcare (which in Argentina is partly government-run) or just administrative staff? Unfortunately, Reason does not provide a source for their claim so we can't check these assumptions, although I suspect you are right in that they mainly consider administrative staff within the national government.

Comment: @SJuan76 *Reason* has a libertarian outlook rather than a liberal outlook, and is consistently rated as have a center-right to right bias.